movie with teenagers committing homicide
I watched this movie some time ago, I think it was shot 5-10 years ago. 
It is the story of two high school guys, one is very smart, the other is some sort of a bully. They commit a homicide to prove they can get away with it. I think the detective knows they are the culprits, but has to outsmart them, so it is a sort of psychological thriller.
I am sure the detective is a woman.

Surely not Murder By Numbers again? ;) [Sorry, it comes up a lot]

@Walt I am afraid so..

No worries. I'll mark it as duplicate.
